# What does $[X,P]=ci I$ imply for the dimension of the underlying space?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ and $P$ be linear operators on a $\mathbb C$ vector space $V$ and $I$ the identity operator. Suppose the commutator

$$[X,P] = XP - PX = ciI$$

for some real, positive constant $c$.

What can we say about the dimension of $V$?

The motivation for this problem was a throw away line by a theoretical physicist in a lecture I saw where he said this necessarily implied $V$ is infinite dimensional. $X$ and $P$ will be recognized by anyone with training in quantum mechanics as labels for two popular operators. However their particularities shouldn't matter as I want to see what we can say about $V$ with just this information.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you define $[X,P] = i(XP - PX)$? (This is standard for physics, but not for math).

Comment: Let me write it out

Comment: Great, thanks ${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In particular, we can show that this is impossible to have $[X,P] = cI$ with $c \neq 0$ in a finite-dimensional vector space with relative ease.

Assume $V$ is finite dimensional.  Fix a basis so that $X$ and $P$ are now matrices over the vectors spaces.  We note that
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{trace}([X,P]) &= 
\operatorname{trace}(XP - PX) = 
\operatorname{trace}(XP) - \operatorname{trace}(PX) 
\\ & = 
\operatorname{trace}(XP) - \operatorname{trace}(XP) = 0
\end{align}
$$
So: if $[X,P] = cI$, then $c = 0$.

Comment: One of those proofs that when you see it you say to yourself: Damn it, I should have thought of that! Thank you.

Comment: The secret is to make it *look* easy :P.  In general, "check the determinant" and "check the trace" are good tricks when $V$ is finite dimensional (or when your operators are sufficiently nice, i.e. compact or of finite rank).

Comment: I somehow thought that the fact that the field was $\mathbb C$ was important. But no. Now I see this result is quite general.

Comment: So how does having infinite-dimensional $V$ fix this?

Comment: @spraff if $V$ is infinite dimensional, we can no longer define a trace function that will work for every linear operator over $V$, so the argument no longer applies.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yeah I get that this argument no longer applies for infinite matrices, but that doesn't mean some other argument wouldn't apply. What is the positive proof that infinite matrices *can* meet this criteria?

Comment: @spraff as the asker implies in his question, there is a classic example from physics, namely the position and momentum operators.  Here's a simplified version of it: take $V$ to be the (infinite dimensional) vector space of smooth functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.  For a function $\psi(x)$ in this vector space, we define
$$
X[\psi(x)] = x\psi(x), \qquad P[\psi(x)] = -ci\,\psi'(x)
$$
where $c$ is a positive constant.  I will leave it to you to verify that
$$
X(P(\psi)) - P(X(\psi)) = ci \psi
$$
for any function $\psi$, which is to say that $XP - PX = ciI$.